# Open an Excel file saved with password for modify

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I would like to open an excel file that is saved with a password for modify with VBScript. My current code VBS code is below, which works, but it keeps popping up with boax asking for a password. How can i open the excel spreadsheet with excel prompting me for a password?

```
Option Explicit

On Error Resume Next

ExcelMacroExample

Sub ExcelMacroExample() 

  Dim xlApp 
  Dim xlBook 

  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\jasons\Documents\TestFile.xlsm",,,,"yep123") 
  xlApp.Visible = True
  xlApp.Run "Refresh_data_ss"
  xlApp.Save
  xlApp.Quit 

  Set xlBook = Nothing 
  Set xlApp = Nothing 

End Sub
```

Comment: There seems to be two passwords that Workbooks.open could ask for. One for open and one for write-access to a write-protected book. Could this have something to do with it? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now I see, there is a password for modify on your file but not for open. [Open password is the fifth parameter to Workbooks.Open, and modify is the sixth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx). SO you need to have the following instead (one more comma):

```
 Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\jasons\Documents\TestFile.xlsm",,,,,"yep123")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the password from an InputBox

```
myPass = InputBox("Write the password: ")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\jasons\Documents\TestFile.xlsm",,,, myPass)
```